# Java code to run other java programs one by one

Tags: java, cmd

Is there any way i can write java program to run other java programs one by one.... I created a bat file cmd.. to run all the java program.. But in CMD.... first program didn't completed and second program start running.. that's what happend.. is there any way in cmd after completed first program than go to second program..if error in first program than don't run all other close overthere.. or please tell me any idea how can i do that with java program..

my bat file look like thins

```
cd C:\
java program1

cd C:\
java program2
pause
```

Please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: You can have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: If the other 'programs' are in the classpath, you could simply write a launcher that takes a list of main class names in the command line and run them.  The 'main' method is just another method, so load each class file using the Class.forName method, introspect to get the 'main' method and execute it, then move to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a batch question that a java question. Although Java can be used for this purpose, it isn't particularly handy for managing processes. It will be easier to stick to batch, especially because you already have a batch file which is almost usable for you.

You can use

```
if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit
```

after a statement in batch to stop execution in case an error happened. In your java program, to make it clear to batch that an error happened, you have to use `System.exit(1);` to exit your program, or any other non-zero value. This exit code is the errorlevel which is tested for in batch.

**EDIT**:

The resulting batch file will then look similar to this:

```
cd C:\
java program1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit

cd C:\
java program2
if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit

pause
```

Comment: what I need to add in bat file?? if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit!! how i can run programs one by one After finished first one than do second one.. Please help me!!

Comment: it will do one by one??

Comment: AFAIK, batch always executes commands serially, which means one by one. the addition makes sure it exits if there was an error. it should be really simple for you to try this out.

Comment: ohh ok, this one is work now..but after complete first program than go to second one right???? I know, I am asking stupid questions.. from first program create file and second program using that files.. so.... that's why.. please tell me.. after total complete first program than run 2nd program right??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java your_class.class");
        p.waitFor();
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java seccond_class.class");
        p.waitFor();
    }
```

In exec method you can execute cmd command

Comment: ohh ok.. do i need to write path?? or only class file..or it will do one by one or same like bat file?? because If first program didn't complete and 2nd start it's not going to work.. I want.. after completed 1st program than strat run 2nd program?? Please help me!!

Comment: It will run this cmd under your classpath if your other java program not under classpath than you need to specify the full path. You need to run each program one by one, I've edited answer with example

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this..

```
cd C:\
start java program1

java program2

pause
```

Comment: what about the program in other directory?? it will do one by one??

Comment: no it won't execute "one by one" it will open a new window and execute program1....if you want you can change the dir after start cmd